# Creating Node for negamax/minimax for Reversi/Othello game

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, nodes

I write AI player for reversi game, and I decide to do it with NegaMax or MiniMax. 
Pseodocode:

```
function negamax(node, depth, α, β, color)
    if node is a terminal node or depth = 0
        return color * the heuristic value of node
    else
        foreach child of node
            val := -negamax(child, depth-1, -β, -α, -color)
            {the following if statement constitutes alpha-beta pruning}
            if val≥β
                return val
            if val≥α
                α:=val
        return α
```

But I need to sent Node to this function, how can I create this node? Like create Node with all possibles  move for state, and then create child-nodes for everyone possible move in Node?

And if you can help with α, β values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node likely is meant to represent a single state.   In games this is the state of the board (for Othello the placement of the pieces, whose move it is. etc.).  Generally in games that use alpha/beta pruning, generating all the next states is possible, but generating all the states for all possible positions is not.

If you're using Java, then a Node object might have a method getChildren() to generate all possible moves from that state, themselves Node objects.

As for the α, β values, these are initialized at Integer.MIN_VALUE and Integer.MAX_VALUE

Comment: So I need override Node.getChildren() method to make him return new board state?

Comment: Yes, a set of new board states